# What is the Postgresql DDL for restoring and backing up a database?

Tags: sql, .net, postgresql, ddl

I am trying to restore and backup a database, from .net, in Postgresql. I can only find information on how to use the pg_restore utility in the command line, but I can't seem to find the DDL that would allow me to do this in sql.

Can someone tell me how to do it or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for DDL commands to restore or backup. If you want to restore or backup, do this in code by creating a batch file, running, that batch file, and deleting that batch file (if it contains sensitive information).